# Android: SugarORM Or condition

Tags: android, sugarorm

I am using SugarORM.

### The selection code:

```
String action = "date_int ASC";

record_list = Select.from(Records_records.class).where(Condition.prop("category").eq("A")).orderBy(action).list(); 
record_list = Select.from(Records_records.class).where(Condition.prop("category").eq("B")).orderBy(action).list();
```

### Question:

The list obtained above is either category being A only or B only.

From the official website it can only generate AND condition **for A and B** as follows:

```
record_list = Select.from(Records_records.class).where(Condition.prop("category").eq("A"), Condition.prop("category").eq("B")).orderBy(action).list();
```

How could I get a list a combined list for category with **(A or B)** and in the order of "date_int ASC"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `whereOr()` for this:

```
record_list = Select.from(Records_records.class).whereOr(Condition.prop("category").eq("A"), Condition.prop("category").eq("B")).orderBy(action).list();
```

It is the OR counterpart to the default AND that `where()` uses.

It is not documented, but you can find it in the [source](https://github.com/chennaione/sugar/blob/master/library/src/test/java/com/orm/query/SelectTest.java#L75-L87):

```
@Test
public void testWhereOr(){
    Select where = Select.from(TestRecord.class).whereOr(Condition.prop("test").eq("satya"));
    assertEquals("(test = ? )", where.getWhereCond());
    assertEquals(1, where.getArgs().length);
    assertEquals("satya", where.getArgs()[0]);

    where = Select.from(TestRecord.class).whereOr(Condition.prop("test").eq("satya"), Condition.prop("prop").eq(2));
    assertEquals("(test = ?  OR prop = ? )", where.getWhereCond());
    assertEquals(2, where.getArgs().length);
    assertEquals("satya", where.getArgs()[0]);
    assertEquals("2", where.getArgs()[1]);
}
```